# How to multiply matching columns between lists?

Tags: r, list, matrix-multiplication, xts

I have 2 `lists`. One is the stock weights and other the returns. Here is an example:

```
a <- matrix(c(0.15, 0.20, 0.10, 0.30, 0.25), 1,5)
colnames(a) <- c("AMBV4", "ARCZ6", "BBAS3", "BBDC4", "BRAP4")
b <- matrix(c(0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.10), 1,4)
colnames(b) <- c("ACES4", "AMBV4", "CMIG3", "CMIG4")
listab<-list(a,b)
c <- matrix(c(0.07, 0.22, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01, 0.12, 0.09, 0.09,0.03, 0.04, 0.21, 0.22, 0.01, 0.04, 0.55, 0.43), 2,8)
colnames(c) <- c("AMBV4", "ARCZ6", "CLSC4", "BBAS3", "BBDC4", "CESP5" , "CMIG3", "BRAP4")
d <- matrix(c(0.05, 0.12, 0.03, 0.04, 0.21, 0.22, 0.01, 0.04, 0.55, 0.43, 0.07, 0.22, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01, 0.12, 0.09, 0.09,0.03, 0.04), 2,10)
colnames(d) <- c("ACES4", "ARCZ6", "AMBV4", "CLSC4", "CMIG3", "CMIG4", "BBAS3", "DASA3", "BBDC4", "BRTP3")
listcd<-list(c,d)
```

I'd like to multiply the weights by the returns but the returns `listcd` have more stocks than weights `listab`. I know how to do it when it has the same number of data, but not like this. Here is how it should end:

```
result1 <- listab[[1]]*listcd[[1]][1, c(1,2,4,5,8)]
result2 <- listab[[1]]*listcd[[1]][2, c(1,2,4,5,8)]
x <- rbind(result1, result2)
result3 <- listab[[2]]*listcd[[2]][1, c(1,3,5,6)]
result4 <- listab[[2]]*listcd[[2]][2, c(1,3,5,6)]
y <- rbind(result3, result4)
list <- list(x,y)

> list
[[1]]
      AMBV4 ARCZ6 BBAS3 BBDC4  BRAP4
[1,] 0.0105 0.002 0.009 0.009 0.1375
[2,] 0.0330 0.010 0.009 0.012 0.1075

[[2]]
     ACES4 AMBV4 CMIG3 CMIG4
[1,] 0.010 0.063 0.220 0.007
[2,] 0.024 0.066 0.172 0.022
```

The final observation that I'd should point out is that the `listcd` is actually a xts objects list (it has the time information).

Any help will be apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
mapply(function(X, Y) t(c(X) * t(Y[, colnames(X)])), listab, listcd)
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
      AMBV4 ARCZ6 BBAS3 BBDC4  BRAP4
[1,] 0.0105 0.002 0.009 0.009 0.1375
[2,] 0.0330 0.010 0.009 0.012 0.1075

[[2]]
     ACES4 AMBV4 CMIG3 CMIG4
[1,] 0.010 0.063 0.220 0.007
[2,] 0.024 0.066 0.172 0.022
```

Here, we use `mapply` to apply a function to each set of values from each list.  We find the names in common, subset and multiply the matrices.  The transpositions and `c(X)` are necessary so that vector recycling allows the multiplication of every weight to every row.

**Note**: the above only works if you are guaranteed every stock that has a weight exists in `listcd`.  If not, use:

```
mapply(
  function(X, Y) {
    names.common <- intersect(colnames(X), colnames(Y))
    t(X * t(Y[,colnames(X)]))
  },
  listab, listcd
)
```

Comment: Very didactic your explanation. Now I understand better the `mapply`. Thank you!

Comment: after that, I'm running `lapply(list, function(x) { x <- rowSums(x) })` to have the daily returns. As I commented in the question, one of the lists (returns) are actually a `xts` objects list. I would like to have as a result a xts object list. Can you give a hint on that? (I need the date information on it.)

Comment: @JorgeDias, I'm not familiar with xts objects, so I can't comment too much on that.  I would note since you're doing the rowsums piece, you should really do `Y[, colnames(X)] %*% c(X)` to get the same result in one step.